# Alignment is getting changed or overlapping when I restore down the web browser

Tags: html, css

My html page div element is getting changed when I restore down the browser but works fine when I maximize it.
when I click on the password field there is a pop-up window displayed to validate the password complexity and every time it will be displayed next to the password field in full screen mode but it will overlap when I click on password field in restore down mode.
I want that to be showed next to the password field in restore down mode also as how it works in full screen mode.
please help

Please find below the HTML and CSS code attached.

```js
    var check = function() {
      if (document.getElementById('psw').value ==
        document.getElementById('confirmPassword').value) {
        document.getElementById('info').style.color = 'green';
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'Matching';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('info').style.color = 'red';
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'Not Matching';
      }
    }
    
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("psw"), y = document.getElementById("confirmPassword");
      if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
     y.type = "text";
      } else {
        x.type = "password";
     y.type = "password";
      }
    }
    
    var psw = document.getElementById("psw");
    var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
    var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var length = document.getElementById("length");
    var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol");
    
    // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
    psw.onfocus = function() {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
    psw.onblur = function() {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    // When the user starts to type something inside the password field
    psw.onkeyup = function() {
      // Validate lowercase letters
      var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
      if(psw.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
        letter.classList.remove("invalid");
        letter.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        letter.classList.remove("valid");
        letter.classList.add("invalid");
      }
      
      // Validate capital letters
      var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
      if(psw.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
        capital.classList.remove("invalid");
        capital.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        capital.classList.remove("valid");
        capital.classList.add("invalid");
      }
    
      // Validate numbers
      var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
      if(psw.value.match(numbers)) {  
        number.classList.remove("invalid");
        number.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        number.classList.remove("valid");
        number.classList.add("invalid");
      }
      
      // Validate length
      if(psw.value.length >= 8) {
        length.classList.remove("invalid");
        length.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        length.classList.remove("valid");
        length.classList.add("invalid");
      }
      
      // Validate Symbols
     var symbols = /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[:;<>?,.@#\]]/g;
     if(psw.value.match(symbols)) {  
        symbol.classList.remove("invalid");
        symbol.classList.add("valid");
      } else {
        symbol.classList.remove("valid");
        symbol.classList.add("invalid");
      }
    }
```

```css
/* Style all input fields */
input {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#myForm select 
{ 
  width: 25%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}


/* Style the submit button */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the container for inputs */
.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: -2000px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 1px 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "?";
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#dbddea">
    
    <h2 align="center"><u>Password Change</u></h2>
    <p align="center"><marquee><h3>Change the password for unix users.</h3></marquee></p>
    
    <div class="container">
      <form>
     <div id=myForm align = "center">
        <label for="usrname">Select Username</label><br>
     <select name="Users">
     <option value="test1">test1</option>
        <option value="test2">test2</option>
     </select>
     </div>
     <div align= "center">
        <input type="password" id="psw" name="psw" onkeyup='check();' placeholder="New Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number, one symbol and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
        <br>
     <div id="message" align = "left">
     <h4>Password must contain the following:</h4>
     <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
     <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
     <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
     <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
     <p id="symbol" class="invalid">A <b>symbol</b></p>
     </div>
     <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" onkeyup='check();' placeholder="Re-type Password" title="Confirm new password" required>
     <br>
     <span id='info'></span>
     
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" style="width: 40px;">Show Password
     </div>
     <div align = "center">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Change Password">
     </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do u want the popup, next to the "New Password" field in Deskop view or overlapping view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plz add this code..

**css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    #message {
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        margin: 0;
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz modify your css code..

**css**

```
#message {
  display:none;
  width: 25%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div id=myForm align = "center">
    <label for="usrname">Select Username</label><br>
    <select name="Users">
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div align= "center">
    <input type="password" id="psw" name="psw" onkeyup='check();' placeholder="New Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number, one symbol and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" onkeyup='check();' placeholder="Re-type Password" title="Confirm new password" required>
    <br>
    <div id="message" align = "left">
        <h4>Password must contain the following:</h4>
        <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
        <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
        <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
        <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
        <p id="symbol" class="invalid">A <b>symbol</b></p>
    </div>
    <span id='info'></span>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" style="width: 40px;">Show Password
    </div>
    <div align = "center">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Change Password">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: But it is now showing the pop-up windows below the password field. I want it to be displayed next to the password field.

Comment: Do u want the popup, next to "Re-type Password" field?

Comment: yes, I want it to be displayed next to the password field.

Comment: :) Next to the password field means not below to the retype password, what I have originally posted is actually working fine in full screen mode, I wanted in the same way when I restore down the browser screen.

Comment: have u checked my latest changes?

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some changes to make it simple.**

```
#message {
  display:none;
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: -2000px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

**Replace with below CSS**

```
#message {
 width: 25%;
}
```

**Make changes in js code as below**

```
psw.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
psw.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}
```

**Change to**

```
psw.onfocus = function() {
  $('#message').slideDown();
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
psw.onblur = function() {
  $('#message').slideUp();
}
```